# Use VBA to insert cell if find specific text/sign

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with 1500 rows and columns from A to EZ, each cell contains the data are very diverse.

I want to use VBA to find each cell that has the sign "/" and what if found "/" will add the letter "cm:" in front of the cell contents.

example:
cell contents "cigarettes/marlboro" to "cm:cigarettes/marlboro" or
cell contents "oral b/toothpaste/toothbrush" becomes "cm:oral b/toothpaste/toothbrush"

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("A1:EZ1500")
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "/") > 0 Then
            r.Value = "cm:" & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: It took me a while to work out why the subroutine was called "marine", but the answer finally surfaced from the depths of my subconscious.

Comment: thanks sir, the code has been going well. sorry but my question is less complete, but if the cell is in accordance (has had cm) to be ignored if it has any cm